# Firebase Deploy: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

Using Firebase, I want to deploy my nextjs project for hosting.

Upon using the  optimization from NextJS I encountered this error.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

This is the output from the command line:

```
=== Deploying to 'web1'...

i  deploying functions, database, storage, hosting
i  functions: preparing codebase firebase-frameworks-web1-142ec for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.
i  functions: preparing .firebase/web1-142ec/functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /blog/.firebase/web1-142ec/functions (70.68 MB) for uploading
i  functions: ensuring required API run.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API run.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: generating the service identity for pubsub.googleapis.com...
i  functions: generating the service identity for eventarc.googleapis.com...

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

This created a new log file that contains the error:

```
[debug] [2023-05-12T13:26:53.454Z] TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: 
    The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:163:11)
    at Object.join (node:path:1172:7)
    at Config.path (/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/config.js:123:45)
    at RulesDeploy.addFile (/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/rulesDeploy.js:37:46)
    at default_1 (/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/storage/prepare.js:39:25)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async chain (/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:38:9)
    at async deploy (/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:95:5)
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe CloudFunctions are not setup correctly. Delete `firebase.json` and run

```
firebase init
```

In my case, it created missing configuration files.